# Issues with string processing in C

Tags: c, string

I'm stuck on a HW assignment where I'm required to write a program that transforms a bunch of English words (in a list separated by new lines in a input .txt file) into a bunch of Pig Latin words (into a list separated by new lines in an output .txt file). I've gotten really close, but the `strncat` function (string concatentation) function that I'm using is somehow throwing in a new line, which really throws off the text that I'm printing to the `stdout` (using it to test for now). Any ideas why this might be happening? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STR_SIZE 100

char * convertToPigLatin (char * strPtr, char * pLatinStr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char str[MAX_STR_SIZE];
   char pStr[MAX_STR_SIZE];
   //char *pStrPtr; 
   FILE *fileInPtr;                                     //Create file name
   FILE *fileOutPtr;    

   fileInPtr = fopen("pigLatinIn.txt", "r");    //Assign text to file
   fileOutPtr = fopen("pigLatinOut.txt", "w");

   //pStrPtr = pStr; 

   if(fileInPtr == NULL)                                //Check if file exists
   {
      printf("Failed");
      exit(-1); 
   }


   do                   //Cycles until end of text
   {
      fgets(str, 29, fileInPtr);                //Assigns word to *char

      str[29] = '\0';                           //Optional: Whole line

      convertToPigLatin(str, pStr); 
      fprintf(fileOutPtr, "%s", pStr); 

   }  while(!feof(fileInPtr));   

   system("pause"); 
}

char * convertToPigLatin (const char * strPtr, char * pStrPtr)
{
   int VowelDetect = 0; 
   int LoopCounter = 0; 
   int consonantCounter = 0; 
   char pStr[MAX_STR_SIZE] = {'\0'};
   char cStr[MAX_STR_SIZE] = {'\0'};
   char dStr[] = {'-','\0'}; 
   char ayStr[] = {'a','y','\0'};
   char wayStr[] = {'w','a','y','\0'};

   pStrPtr = pStr; 

   while (*strPtr != '\0')
   {
      if (*strPtr == 'a' || *strPtr == 'e' || *strPtr == 'i' || *strPtr == 'o' || *strPtr == 'u' || VowelDetect ==1)
      {
         strncat(pStr, strPtr, 1); 
         VowelDetect = 1; 
      }
      else
      {
         strncat(cStr, strPtr, 1); 
         consonantCounter++; 
      }
      *strPtr++;
   }
   strcat(pStr, dStr); 
   if (consonantCounter == 0)  
   {
      strcat(pStr, wayStr);
   }
   else
   {
      strcat(pStr, cStr);
      strcat(pStr, ayStr);
   }  
   printf("%s", pStr);                       

 //  return pStrPtr; 
}
```

Comment: Would you like quick and painful or slow and painless?

Comment: My *guess* would be that you have at least one line that's less characters than the `29` you're reading with `fgets()`, and therefore you have an embedded CR or LF in the string which your loop just `strcat`s on to your string, as you don't exclude either of those characters. What made you just decide to arbitrarily read 29 characters at a time and assume it was a single line?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think `strncat()` is adding a newline, it's just that `fgets()` is reading one that's already in the input file. You should strip it out before running it through `convertToPigLatin()`.

Comment: `do/fgets/while` without checking the return value of `fgets` is a poor input loop structure. If `fgets` fails (returning null), your loop body will run anyway, and re-process the last line again that was read in the previous iteration.

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of oddities in this code, but the problem you're asking about is created by your while loop in `convertToPigLatin`. You loop while `*strPtr != '\0'`, and `\n` is certainly not `\0`, so you are adding that to `pStr`.

Now for the rest of the code, just a few comments:

- Using `strncat` to copy one character is odd usage. Typically, one would use simple character assignment instead (as in `str1[i] = str2[j]`)
- `*strPtr++` is incrementing the pointer and dereferencing it, but then doing nothing with the dereferenced value. You just want `strPtr++` there.
- You can create a string literal using `char str[] = "some string"`. You don't need to use array initialization syntax.

Those are the ones that jumped out at me without a detailed reading. Good luck on your future assignments.

Edit to add that stepping through your code with a debugger is very valuable in these cases. You would see exactly where the newline is being added.

Comment: Concatenating with `str1[i] = str2[j]`, `str` loses it `\0`.  (Add `str1[i+1] = '\0'` ?)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies not in strncat, but in your input:

```
fgets(str, 29, fileInPtr);                //Assigns word to *char
str[29] = '\0';                           //Optional: Whole line
```

If you enter something other than 29 characters, the hard return is not overwritten. Use this instead:

```
str[strlen(str)-1] = 0;
```

.. actually, this will always overwrite the 29th character, even if it isn't a hard return (when you entered *more* than 29 characters). So a better solution would be

```
char *ptr = strchr(str, '\n');
if (ptr) *ptr = 0;
```

You cannot use `MAX_STR_SIZE` for this either (which you defined-but didn't use in your code), since fgets

> [r]eads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

-- the last character could be the terminating zero, or a hard return.

Comment: `str[strlen(str)-1] = 0` is problematic.  In unusual situations, `strlen(str)` is 0. OP will not likely experience them here, but avoid that idiom.

Comment: Agreed (it needs a check for `strlen(str) > 0`, or (short) `if (str[0])`) for belt-and-suspenders safety. But when is it needed? A single binary 0 at the end of the input file, right after the last newline perhaps?

Comment: 1) Any line that begins with a binary 0, such as "\0Hello\n", not necessarily a single `\0` nor near the EOF. `fgets()` stops on `\n`, not `\0`. 2) On an I/O error (or _maybe_ EOF) where the return value of `fgets()` is not checked, like here, leaves the `str` in an undefined state. 3) Not sure, but maybe when `fgets(str, 1, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

@selbie is right ,

```
*strPtr++;
```

==>

```
++strPtr;
```

also add this before call convertToPigLatin

```
if(str[0] == '\0')
        break;
```

And it works,the pigLatinOut.txt show work in Latin,but all in one line!

like this : (I know nothing about Latin,is that waht you want?):

pigLatinIn.txt

```
hello world!
I am line one!
I am line two!
I am line three!
```

pigLatinOut.txt

```
ð¬Œ¿\q·ð¬Œ¿\q·ð¬Œ¿\q·ð¬Œ¿\q·
```